# How to make an embed reactions menu which loads its elements from a .json file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm trying to make a menu which shows my guild custom emojis list (see the 
picture).

[image: picture]

I have a .json file, the emojis and the emojis codes are stored on it, I'm using it to get the ability to store more emojis in future.

[image]

This is the code that i use to make this embed:

```js
execute(message) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const Emojis = require('./emojis.json');
        const keys = Object.keys(Emojis);
        var i = 0
        const embed = {
            "title": "Server emojis list:",
            "color": 1056085,
            "timestamp": new Date(),
            "footer": {
                "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/469276415746113568/f86e89f362f1df6dc1f996818ef49e7a.png?size=1024",
                "text": "Dz Gamers Community"
            },
            "fields": [{
                "name": "Emoji:",
                "value": `${Emojis[keys[i+0]]}\n${Emojis[keys[i+1]]}\n${Emojis[keys[i+2]]}\n${Emojis[keys[i+3]]}\n${Emojis[keys[i+4]]}\n`,
                "inline": true
            }, {
                "name": "Emoji code:",
                "value": `**${keys[i+0]}\n${keys[i+1]}\n${keys[i+2]}\n${keys[i+3]}\n${keys[i+4]}\n**`,
                "inline": true
            }]
        };
```

I'm using reactions collectors for that, but I'm not sure about how to edit the embed fields.

```js
message.channel.send({embed})
    .then(async embedMessage => {
        await embedMessage.react('◀')
        await embedMessage.react('▶')
        const emoji = {
            NEXT_PAGE: '▶',
            PREV_PAGE: '◀',
        }
        const collector = new Discord.ReactionCollector(embedMessage, (reaction, user) => Object.values(emoji).includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot, {});
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case emoji.NEXT_PAGE:
                    {
                        //Edit embed here (Next page)
                        embedMessage.reactions.get(emoji.PREV_PAGE).remove(message.author)
                        break;
                    }
                case emoji.PREV_PAGE:
                    {
                        //Edit embed here (Previous page)
                        embedMessage.reactions.get(emoji.PREV_PAGE).remove(message.author)
                        break;
                    }
            };
        });
        collector.on('end', () => embedMessage.delete());
    })
}
```

So now, I want a way to make the bot edit the embed, to load 5 emojis (in order) on every menu page, so i think that it should be a var, the var value will be the page number, then i will be able to use is on `keys[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a neat little function to help you out with this. It would iterate through the entries of your json file, and add those needed on the specified page to the embed. Then, it would collect reactions, and call itself again to display a different page.

This is much easier to show with an example. Make sure to understand the code before you just copy and paste it.

```js
// Require json file.
const emojis = require('./emojis.json');

// Define our function.
async function list(listMsg, page, increment) {
  const entries = Object.entries(emojis);

  // Set up base embed.
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(1056085)
    .setTitle('**Server Emojis**')
    .setDescription(`Page **${page}** of ${Math.ceil(entries.length/increment)}`)
    .setFooter('Dz Gamers Community', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/469276415746113568/f86e89f362f1df6dc1f996818ef49e7a.png?size=1024')
    .setTimestamp(listMsg ? listMsg.createdAt : undefined);

  // Add fields to embed.
  const emojiField = [];
  const stringField = [];

  for (let [emoji, string] of entries.slice((page - 1) * increment, (page * increment) + 1)) {
    emojiField.push(emoji);
    stringField.push(string);
  }

  embed.addField('Emoji:', emojiField.join('\n'), true);
  embed.addField('String:', stringField.join('\n'), true);

  // Edit/send embed.
  if (listMsg) await listMsg.edit(embed);
  else listMsg = await message.channel.send(embed);

  // Set up page reactions.
  const lFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '◀' && page !== 1 && user.id === message.author.id;
  const lCollector = listMsg.createReactionCollector(lFilter, { max: 1 });

  lCollector.on('collect', async () => {
    rCollector.stop();
    await listMsg.clearReactions();
    list(listMsg, page - 1, increment);
  });

  const rFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '▶' && entries.length > page * increment && user.id === message.author.id;
  const rCollector = listMsg.createReactionCollector(rFilter, { max: 1 });

  rCollector.on('collect', async () => {
    lCollector.stop();
    await listMsg.clearReactions();
    list(listMsg, page + 1, increment);
  });

  if (page !== 1) await listMsg.react('◀');
  if (entries.length > page * increment) await listMsg.react('▶');
}

// Send the list; page 1, and 5 shown on each page.
list(undefined, 1, 5)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Since some parts may look confusing and be hard to understand by their appearance, here's some further explanation:

- `Math.ceil(entries.length / increment)`

  - Dividing the length of `entries` by the amount of elements that are shown on each page (`increment`) will give us how many pages there should be in total. We [ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) it, because if there are any remaining, we need another page for them.
- `embed.setTimestamp(listMsg ? listMsg.createdAt : undefined)`

  - If we set the timestamp of the embed each time we edit the message, then it's not the time the message was sent. So, if we're editing a message, we set it to that message timestamp's; if we're sending a new one, we use a new timestamp ([`RichEmbed.setTimestamp()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp) uses the current time when no value is provided).
- `const [emoji, string] of entries.slice(...)`

  - `[emoji, string]` extracts the key and value of the entry and assigns them respectively.
- `entries.slice((page - 1) * increment, (page * increment) + 1)`

  - `(page - 1) * increment` is the starting index to slice from. `page` is not zero-based, so we must subtract one from it. Then, we multiply it times the amount of elements that should be shown on each page, because all those have already been shown.
  - `(page * increment) + 1` is the ending index to slice to. We don't subtract from `page` this time because that would put as back at the starting point - `increment` elements have already been shown. We have to add one to it because the element at the `end` index is not included in [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- `entries.length > page * increment`

  - We can check if there's further entries by testing if the length of `entries` is longer than the position of the last element shown.

Comment: I will take some time to understand how the code functions.
For now, there is this [problem](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/574978692527161345/589924900773429297/bandicam_2019-06-16_22-06-36-790.mp4) when you react ◀ to back to the previous page.

Comment: Are you using the exact code? It appears as if the bot is triggering its own collector, but the filter should prevent that. I notice that the Emoji and String fields are flipped for you. You can rename them if you wish to reflect your json setup.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same code, and i noticed that too.
I think that there is some lag caused by my connection.

Comment: how to make it shows 5 emojis only, now it shows 6, what should i change?

Comment: I found the mistake in the code - the collectors weren't stopped, so there were duplicates created. Use the edited version. As for the amount of emojis, you can change the last parameter of the function.

Comment: excuse me, I tried to add a timer but it didn't work, so i added a new collector with a timer, so when the new collector stops, the embed will be deleted, but now i have Unknown Message errors on the console, so i used `if (!lCollector.ended){lCollector.stop()}` (rCollector too) but same, then i tried to use .catch(), but it still show some errors, so what should i do?

Comment: If all collectors ended, what still needs the message to be exist?